# Gitlab LFS repo change to NFS

Tags: gitlab, git-lfs

We want to change the Gitlab default LFS repo to a mounted NFS share.
I have mounted the NFS share to the gitlab server and changed the gitlab.rb file to:

gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['lfs_storage_path'] = '/mounted-nfs-share/lfs-objects'

It is still using the default local gitlab server. Service and server have been restarted.

What am I missing ?